# Count of records in the 2nd table according to the values in the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables like this:

[image: Schema]

And I would like to get this:

[image: Output]

There are all rows from Notification table (selected attributes). 
Then Name of Location where the notif. occurred (`Notification.Location_ID = Location.ID`)
and count of processes that happened in the same location during the time period of the notif. (`COUNT(Process.ID) WHERE Notification.Location_ID = Process.Location_ID AND DateTime > Begin AND DateTime < End`)

I think I have a problem with joining Process table properly.
How should the whole SQL query look to get the wanted output? Thx.

Comment: Please don't post data as an image; it isn't helpful to the volunteers your are asking to help you. Post data as formatted `text`, or even better post it as DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the join between the first two tables is Ok, so, I would propose you to add the following subquery at the end of the SELECT clause before FROM to calculate the counter for the rows.

```
(SELECT Count(*) FROM Process WHERE Process.Location_ID = Location.ID) AS Counter
```

If you have included the third table (Process) in the join, you have to eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to join `process` on common location ID and the timestamp being in the time range.

```
SELECT n.name,
       n.begin,
       n.end,
       l.name,
       count(p.id)
       FROM notification n
            LEFT JOIN location l
                      ON l.id = n.location_id
            LEFT JOIN process p
                      ON p.location_id = n.location_id
                         AND p.datetime >= n.begin
                         AND p.datetime < n.end
       GROUP BY n.name,
                n.begin,
                n.end,
                l.name;
```